# 1-of-k encoding Apache Spark In Java

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, categorical-data

I'm trying to test this code that I found in Spark documentation, in order to deal with categorical features in Apache Spark using Java:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder().master("local[4]")
            .appName("1-of-K encoding Test")
            .getOrCreate();
List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create(0, "a"),
            RowFactory.create(1, "b"),
            RowFactory.create(2, "c"),
            RowFactory.create(3, "a"),
            RowFactory.create(4, "a"),
            RowFactory.create(5, "c")
    );
StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{ 
new StructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, false,Metadata.empty()),
new StructField("category", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())
    });
Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);
StringIndexerModel indexer = new StringIndexer()
.setInputCol("category")
.setOutputCol("categoryIndex")
.fit(df);
```

But I'm getting this error; the fit function can't be called

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating the df in the longer route? More efficient way would be :

```
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val df = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "d"), (4, "e"), (5, "f"))).toDF("id", "category")

  val newDf = new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol("category")
    .setOutputCol("categoryIndex")
    .fit(df)
    .transform(df)
    .show;
```

Which gives output:

```
+---+--------+-------------+
| id|category|categoryIndex|
+---+--------+-------------+
|  0|       a|          2.0|
|  1|       b|          3.0|
|  2|       c|          4.0|
|  3|       d|          5.0|
|  4|       e|          0.0|
|  5|       f|          1.0|
+---+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you it works for me now, (i found the example in Apache Mlib Documentation )